# How to mark some points on 2D heat map in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am using simple scheme for plot 2D heat map from my data like this:

```
set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolation 5,5
splot "file"
```

Now i need to mark few points on this data, maybe with white color. I tried to do:

```
splot "file"; plot "points"
```

and it's not working and writes: "Can't use pm3d for 2d plots".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the file look like?  You can do:

```
splot 'file' with pm3d, 'points' with points linecolor rgb "white"
```

depending on what `'points'` looks like though, you might need to add a using specification:

```
splot 'file' with pm3d, 'points' using 1:2:(0.0) with points linecolor rgb "white"
```

Comment: thank you a lot, it helps!
my files looks like
x y z
where z was a color, in my case magnetic field amplitude