# Gnuplot - Plot data points on 2D contour plot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, contour

I want to plot some data points ([M_Coord_Plain.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuOMhHu6zzXexC8_ncB6jEImvK4h)) onto a 2D contour projection (which is made by data on [Contours.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AuOMhHu6zzXexDAZOxEtaAXfDhs-)).

I have found similar answers on these posts: [How to mark some points on 2D heat map in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109657/how-to-mark-some-points-on-2d-heat-map-in-gnuplot/13110402#13110402), [Overlaying points onto a pm3d map?](http://comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot.narkive.com/XcZyny0j/overlaying-points-onto-a-pm3d-map) 
, but unfortunately these don't seem to work in my case.

First i set the options:

```
set pm3d explicit   
unset surface     # Switch off the surface    
set view map      # Set a bird eye (xy plane) view    
set contour       # Plot contour lines    
set key outside    
set cntrparam cubicspline   # smooth out the lines    
unset colorbox
```

and then i plot with the splot command:

```
splot 'Contours.txt' using 1:2:3 notitle with pm3d,\
      'M_Coord_Plain.txt' with points nocontour using 1:2:(0) pt 7
```

The resulted plot is only the contour 2D projection but with no points on it and with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked, but the following changes had to be made:

1. Include a space between each line in the data file of points (M_Coord_Plain.txt) because the splot command needs this format.
2. Delete the *unset surface* command and replace it with *set surface* command because the data points are plotted on the surface. However this has as a result the points to seem vague since the corresponding color for zero value (the defined third column :(0) ) is by default dark purple.
3. So we can use a black and white color palette and define a wide range colorbox range in order to have a big contrast between zero and high contour values.

So the commands to plot the requested plot are:

```
set pm3d explicit
set surface
set view map  # Set a bird eye (xy plane) view
set contour  # Plot contour lines
set key outside
set cntrparam cubicspline  # Smooth out the lines
set cntrparam levels discrete 3.197,3.552  # Plot the selected contours
unset colorbox
set cbrange [0:7000]  # Set the color range of contour values.
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'white', 1 'black' )
set style line 1 lc rgb '#4169E1' pt 7 ps 2
splot 'Contours.txt' using 1:2:3 with pm3d notitle,\
      'M_Coord_Plain.txt' using 1:2:(0) with points ls 1 notitle
```

The resulted plot is [this](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AM068mCl%2DP%5FiF44&cid=DE35CFBA7B848CE3&id=DE35CFBA7B848CE3%219682&parId=DE35CFBA7B848CE3%218750&o=OneUp).

Comment: How to reproduce this example in Gnuplot 5.4.1
I get the alert: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d".